# Execute multiple queries in single pyhive.execute command

Tags: python, pyhive

Using pyhive, is it possible to execute multiple hql's like 'CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ITEM_KEY BIGINT );CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (ITEM_NAME BIGINT );'.

Sample code

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host=host
                       , port=port, username=user
                       , password=passwd
                       , auth=auth)
cursor = conn.cursor()
query= 'CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ITEM_KEY BIGINT );CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (ITEM_NAME BIGINT );'. 
cursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you split your query and execute them one by one?

```
qList = query.split(";")
for q in qList:
    cursor.execute(q)
```

Comment: There are several places i m sending multiple queries in single command to save some time. I already have these codes using paramiko . trying to change to use pyhive

Comment: This answer does not seem to answer if we can still run multiple queries in one go, from pyhive.

Comment: @sharku What is your take on that? Your answer will be useful to many more people, then

Comment: @thegreatcoder I have not take on this since I never used pyhive. I just saw how to solve the problem with just python.

Comment: you should use an actual SQL parser, in the case of embedded `;` characters. `sqlparse` works well